# Implementing SitePoint's Infinite Scolling in rails by Ilya Bodrov-Krukowski

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rubygems

I am implementing, http://www.sitepoint.com/infinite-scrolling-rails-basics/, into my own project.

It works when I type URL directly to browser after I have implemented it in my own project. However, it does not work if I link_to from a different page. It goes back to regular will_paginate, then I hit "reload" button on browser, it starts tp work again.

However, I don't want my users to hit "reload" button every time for making infinite scrolling to work. What might cause this and how can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by turbolinks

However, it is not a fix by installing jquery-turbolinks.

After reading turbolinks documents, temporarily disable turbolink for that particular link with

```
<a href="/">Home (via Turbolinks)</a>
 <div id="some-div" data-no-turbolink>
  <a href="/">Home (without Turbolinks)</a>
 </div>
```